# Why method now in Python is obtained as datetime.datetime.now instead of datetime.time.now?

Tags: python, datetime, time, standard-library

I would like to know why the method **now** was implemented under the datetime.datetime label instead of the datetime.time?

For example to obtain today's date on python you do the following.

```
import datetime
print datetime.date.today()
```

but you can't the same for the time now, I mean

```
print datetime.time.now()
```

Instead you have to do the following:

```
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Now" is a point in time. That means date matters; if it's noon now, yesterday noon is not also now. (Time of day also matters; 9 AM today is also not now.) Thus, it makes sense to have a `datetime.datetime.now`, but not a `datetime.time.now`. It could make sense to have a `datetime.time.currentlocaltime` or `datetime.time.currentutctime`, but those methods don't exist. You could put in a feature request if you want.

Comment: Good answer. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) explicitly say that `datetime.time` is "An idealized time, independent of any particular day", and "now" is obviously not independent of any particular day…

Comment: One little quibble: Unlike `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.time` is implicitly a local or tz-aware time of day; a current UTC `time` only makes sense for a (naive or aware) local time where the local timezone is UTC. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects): "A time object represents a (local) time of day… subject to adjustment via a `tzinfo` object."